# Juniper SSG5 DDNS https socket creation failed

Tags: https, juniper, ddns, ssg5

I have a Juniper SSG5 firewall, Version: 6.3.0r19.0, that is on a dynamic IP. We are using DDNS service from dyndns. The service is supported by the SSG device.

There has been no problems getting it to work using http only. 
My problem arises when changing to https.

When using http i get "good" and "nochg" replies from dyndns. 
It only replies  "no-init" when using https.

More details is found below, I am fresh out if ideas as to get this to work. My knowledge on certs and CA's is not extensive.

I have been using this KB article as a basis for the config:

Juniper KB, configre DDNS on screenOS device,
http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB4582

NOTE:
The inhere mentioned cert, Geotrust certificate, as of  is no longer valid. 
As mentioned here, 
http://forums.juniper.net/t5/ScreenOS-Firewalls-NOT-SRX/DynDNS-Certificate-Provider-Changed-ScreenOS-DDNS-Client-Broken/td-p/143914

That cert was changed for a DigiCert cert as of May 22, 2012.
I have used FF to find and export the certs before importing them to the SSG device. The digicerts used on members.dyndns.org/ is as far as i can understand, please correct me if i am wrong,

`DigiCert Global Root CA, with serial number:[08:3B:E0:56:90:42:46:B1:A1:75:6A:C9:59:91:C7:4A]`

and

`DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA with serial number: [01:FD:A3:EB:6E:CA:75:C8:88:43:8B:72:4B:CF:BC:91]`

I have even tried to download them from the digicert home webpage and installing the certs i download there and afterwards used the serial numbers to see if the certs are identical.

Perhaps worth noting is that, when installed, both ca-certs is named "DigiCert Global Root CA", but serial numbers and expire dates are matching the information in get from the page by clicking the url padlock in FF. When using

`openssl x509 -in DigiCertGlobalRootCA -text -noout`

It seems that both certs has CN="DigiCert Global Root CA".

I have tried installing them the root CA first and then the intermediate, in reverse order, only Root, only intermediate. The downloaded from DigiCert and the FF certs. In FF i have tried with and without chain. I have even tried adding all the DigiCerts I found in FF.

Regardless of the above efforts i still get:

```
DDNS: Triggering update for 1
ddns: server members.dyndns.org resolved to 204.13.248.111
DDNS: connect error
socket creation failed
ddns: update failed, fail cnt 4, retry after 60 min
```

Using this example from Dyndns, 
From here, [sorry don't have the rep for more URL's]: 
help.dyn.com/remote-access-api/perform-update/

Using this i can update the ip using https with FF.

username:password@members.dyndns.org/nic/update?hostname=yourhostname&myip=ipaddress&wildcard=NOCHG&mx=NOCHG&backmx=NOCHG

I also found this Juniper KB article and tested the command there,

To load Intermediate CA Certificate into Netscreen Firewall

kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB6779&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1237138980966

```
set pki x509 def cert-path full [Enter]
save [Enter]
```

But the only change I can see is that if I install a intermediate cert both the intermediate and the root is installed at the same time when installing the intermediate cert, but does not help me with my problem.

Somewhere I found that maybe disabling alg on dns might help. 
I have tried that, but I cannot see that it makes any difference.

NOTE, ntp and dns is enabled and working. A reset has been done after the presumed correct certs has been loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following answer from Juniper Community.

> This is a known issue in 6.3r19.  I would recommend using 6.3r18.

By using the following guide i changed the version from, 6.3r19 to 6.3r18:
http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB13672

**Note**, it is worth removing the Digicert certs before downgrade. They changed in some strange way after downgrade. I removed after downgrade and reinstalled them and after that i got a reply "good" form dyndns.

Here is the post on the juniper forum:
http://forums.juniper.net/t5/ScreenOS-Firewalls-NOT-SRX/Juniper-SSG5-DDNS-https-socket-creation-failed/td-p/278154#M30368